# CSS gradient in IE different for button than link

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I have this CSS class that styles using gradients:

```
.zui-btn
{
padding:5px 15px; margin:0; border:1px solid #ccc;text-shadow: 0px 1px #fff; text-align:center;
background: #ffffff;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #dddddd 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#dddddd));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#dddddd 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#dddddd 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#dddddd 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 0%,#dddddd 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#dddddd');  
}
```

I have it applied to a link and a button. But the result doesn't come through in IE8, IE9 for the link. See http://jsfiddle.net/88mSc/14/

```
<a href="#" class="zui-btn">Modify</a>    
<button type="button" class="zui-btn">Hello World</button>
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Should note that in Internet Explorer 10, you don't have this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug you can workaroung by setting the display to `inline-block`.

Don't ask me why.

Comment: Ah I remember now the old rule about IE8: when in doubt, `display:inline-block`. Thanks!